# how to use reset with const shared pointer to non const object?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, boost-multi-index

I am trying to reset shared pointer which is member of struct  coming from iterator of container with constant structs"elements".
the code does not compile, with error:

```
cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend> &'
```

this error tells me that const shared pointer is not allowed to be used by reset??!! is this true?
if so how can i cast this const shared pointer into non const to be used by reset??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not attemps to do anything that could delete the pointer hold by a `const shared_ptr<T>`, like calling `reset()` on it!

If you do something like `delete myConstSharedPtr.get();`, `delete` will get called again on the stored pointer when the reference count will reach 0, basically causing a double free error.

Also, you should reconsider your design and decide wether `shared_ptr` is really what you want to use here.

---

Ultimately, as a very last resort, if the const'ness of this `shared_ptr` comes from an external library which should not impose this `const` restriction and which you cannot properly patch, then `const_cast` is made for such situation. But forget it, you don't want to use that, really.

Still there ? Here is how to use `const_cast` to force reset a `const shared_ptr`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void forceReset(const std::shared_ptr<T> ptr){
   const_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>&>(ptr).reset();
}
```

WARNING: If this code does what you want at first sight, it means that the bad library you depend on leaks memory. Indeed, there is no way to *detach* a `shared_ptr`, that is, destroying it without updating the reference count. It means that unless one of the shared pointer referring to the force-deleted resource is dynamically allocated and never deleted until the end of the program, a double free will occur resulting in undefined behaviour... likely a nasty crash.

But if you still want to proceed, which you should definitely not, you could take advantage of that to prevent the reference counter to reach zero at the cost of a small memory leak which will be cleaned-up at program exit. Leaking memory will not lead to any kind of undefined behavior.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void forceReset(const std::shared_ptr<T> ptr){
   //This leaked shared_ptr will prevent automatic deletion
   new std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
   const_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>&>(ptr).reset();
}
```

**Just another disclaimer: I strongly discourage anyone to use this hack. I gave it to discuss the risk of messing with smart pointers and `const_cast`. Please, consider one more time patching the offending library or using another one.**

Comment: +1Ultimately, as a very last resort, if the const'ness of this shared_ptr comes from an external library which you should not impose this const restriction and which you cannot properly patch.....this is my situation

Comment: If this answers your question, could you please accept it ?

Comment: you did not tell me how to use const_cast to change const shared_ptr???i think const_cast does not work...

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `const shared_ptr<T>` then you cannot change what it points to. That is the nature of `const`. Thus, you cannot call `reset`, because that would change what it points to.

You can create a non-`const` copy, and change what that points to, but that still won't change the original `const` pointer.

Comment: You can change the content of the variable to which a `const shared_ptr<T>` points to but you cannot change the value of the pointer it holds. The first sentence is ambiguous, could you clarify, please ?
Also, doing a non-const *local* copy of a `const shared_ptr<T>` looks pointless to me as it only incur an overhead without providing any benefit.